# How to Enable Logging in Android programatically

Tags: android, logging, android-widget

I am working on an Android Application where I need to display log information when I execute the .apk file in release mode based on some condition.
It can be like below:

```
if(debug)
   display log inf.
else
  normal execution
```

I will set this variable to true to enable debug mode to display log information.
Can anyone help me in achieving this feature.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the Log-function of Android via

```
Log.v(YourClass.class.simpleName(), "this is your verbose log text");
```

If you connect your phone to your computer and install the apk-file on your mobile phone (via Eclipse) you can use the phone like the emulator and watch the log entries in the DDMS.

See also: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html